# Working with layout object attributes and variables in FileMaker

Tags: filemaker

This is the first time I'm encountering `GetLayoutObjectAttribute` and I am having serious issues with it. My variable `$web` won't set. I think it's because `PD_WebV` isn't the right object name to refer to, but I don't know how to find the right object name. I can't find the objects name when I hit `Edit Layout`, so does anyone know how to find an layout objects name?

```
Loop
     Pause/Resume Script [Duration (seconds): 1]
     Set Variable[$Web; Value: GetLayoutObjectAttribute("PD_WebV";"content")]
     If[$Web="done"]
          #execute if statements
```

[image]

After Edit:

After some troubleshooting, I found out that `PD_WebV` is the right object name to refer and it's refered to correctly, so my new question is why doesn't the script go to the line `If[$Web="done"]` and how could I fix it? Ss my `If` statement not evaluating something it should be? Is my `$web` variable never set to `done` or is the issue something completely different? Would the problem possibly have to do with my `WebDirect` sharing settings? Any guidance would help. Thanks.

After, After Edit:
So now that my application is getting past `Set Variable[$Web; Value: GetLayoutObjectAttribute("PD_WebV";"content")]`, the variable `$web` only equals `<HTML></HTML>`. Does anyone know a way, without using javascript, to test the inside of the `html` tags?

Also, I printed the `bounds` of the webViewer `PD_WebV` that I can't locate on the layout but am referring to in the script. The bounds that are printed are different each time I run the script. Is the usual or unusual? My source is also `about:blank` so it doesn't look like I'm sourcing from a URL

Comment: What version of FileMaker are you using?

Comment: Filemaker 14 my friend, but I also have 13 still installed since 13 is 32 bit and 14 is 64 bit

Comment: Gotcha, and did you add the name `PD_WebV` to your WebViewer's **Name** field in the inspector?

Comment: In that screenshot you posted, the place where you have "ProjWonPortal" is your layout object name. If you were going to use `GetLayoutObjectAttribute` on it, it would look like this: `GetLayoutObjectAttribute("ProjWonPortal"; "content")`

Comment: Yea, that was a different layout object, but thx for the info

Comment: Ah gotcha. Np and good luck.

Comment: Thx. i'm going to need it

Comment: "*the variable $web only equals <HTML></HTML>*" That doesn't tell us anything, one way or another. What do you see if you load the same page in a browser, then choose "View Page Source"?

Comment: The real issue I'm having is locating this webviewer that doesn't seem to be anywhere on the page. I even printed the bounds of the webviewer, and I clicked the area between the stated bounds and nothing seemed to be there. Is there any layout tricks to hide webviewers? Also, I'll probably open this up to a new question. Thanks for your help. It's greatly appreciated and you'll be getting the +50 bounty. I'm just keeping the question open for a little longer so it may get more attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is my $web variable never set to done or is the issue something
>   completely different?

If you're doing:

```
Set Variable[$Web; Value: GetLayoutObjectAttribute("PD_WebV";"content")]
```

then the only time

```
$Web="done"
```

will return true is when the web page loaded into your web viewer contains *exactly* the string "done" (in practical terms, that's never).

I have already suggested in a comment that you test for:

```
PatternCount ( $webpage ; "</html>" )
```

This is assuming you want the subsequent steps to execute only after the page has finished loading. The entire script would look something like this:

```
Loop
     Pause/Resume Script [Duration (seconds): 1]
     Set Variable[$Web; Value: GetLayoutObjectAttribute("PD_WebV";"content")]
     Exit Loop If [ PatternCount ( $webpage ; "</html>" ) ]
End Loop     
# execute statements
```

You might also want to add a counter to the loop and exit the script after n trials.

Comment: Before, I put your `Exit Loop If [ PatternCount ( $webpage ; "</html>" ) ]` in the wrong spot in the code. Now its in the right spot and the code gets past that conditional. Thanks.

Comment: @pHorseSpec Is your question not answered?

Comment: yea, you answer my `After edit` question, but I'm not getting any HTML from my webviewer other than `<HTML></HTML>`, so I'm trying to figure out how to create an if statement based on what's inside the html tags while not using javascript because it's not my strongest language.

Comment: "*I'm not getting any HTML from my webviewer other than <HTML></HTML>*"  I don't see how I can help you with that without more information. Perhaps you should post a new question (and close - again - this one).

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I reread your question.

To set the object name for your webviewer so that the `GetLayoutObjectAttribute` function works you need to set it in the **Name** field in the inspector when you have the webviewer selected.

e.g.:

[image]

After that your variable should populate.

## Be aware

What it will populate with will be **all of the html from the browser**, i.e. not a boolean true/false liek your conditional suggests.

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but to be able to determine a result from your web viewer you'll need to either parse the HTML to see if it's content contains what you're looking for or within the code you're setting the webviewer with, fire a javascript function that calls back to the FileMaker file using a FileMaker url.

Comment: Is the `Name` field the top field in the position tab of inspector?

Comment: Yep, that's correct. That name field is really the "layout object name" field.

Comment: Would `If [not (IsEmpty ($Web))]` be better?

Comment: No, the problem is that even if whatever you set to the web viewer fails, html will still be generated (the webviewer still need to build something to show you that it failed) so it will always be full. Check out this article from Soliant Consulting on [javascript in in the webviewer](http://www.soliantconsulting.com/blog/2014/04/getting-started-javascript-and-filemaker) as far as getting data back out.

Comment: @pHorseSpec In most cases, you would do something like `Exit Loop If [ PatternCount ( $webpage ; "</html>" ) ] ` - although I did encounter pages that do not have a closing </html> tag.